# Factory method design pattern Typescript

Tags: typescript, design-patterns

im just learning design pattern and i do not know whats the benefit of abstraction in below code: i rewrite the code and still work the way we want.

you can see the original code from [here](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/factory-method/typescript/example)

```
class Creator {
  public factoryMethod() {}

  public someOperation(): string {
    const product = this.factoryMethod();
    return `Creator: The same creator's code has just worked with ${product}`;
  }
}

class ConcreteCreator1 extends Creator {
  public factoryMethod(): string {
    return '{Result of the ConcreteProduct1}';
  }
}

class ConcreteCreator2 extends Creator {
  public factoryMethod(): string {
    return '{Result of the ConcreteProduct2}';
  }
}

function clientCode(creator: Creator) {
  console.log(
    "Client: I'm not aware of the creator's class, but it still works."
  );
  console.log(creator.someOperation());
}

console.log('App: Launched with the ConcreteCreator1.');
clientCode(new ConcreteCreator1());
console.log('');

console.log('App: Launched with the ConcreteCreator2.');
clientCode(new ConcreteCreator2());
```

Answer (score 0):

Comparing your code to the original, you have changed the `abstract class Creator` into a concrete `class Creator`.  This means that you can now instantiate this class by calling `new Creator()`.

The problem is that your base `Creator` class hasn't *really* implemented the `factoryMethod()` method.  You have made it into a concrete method that does nothing and returns `void`.  When you call `clientCode(new Creator());` you get an output which is not what you want:

> "Creator: The same creator's code has just worked with undefined"

#### Why We Use Abstract Classes

```js
abstract class Creator {
    public abstract factoryMethod(): Product;
/* ... */
```

The original code example uses the `abstract class Creator` to establish the contract which all concrete creators must fulfill.  It says: *"in order to be a `Creator`, you must have a `factoryMethod` that returns a `Product`"*.

**All concrete classes which `extend` `Creator` must implement the `factoryMethod` method.  But the base `abstract class Creator` does not need to implement it.**

The missing implementation is not a problem because an abstract class cannot be instantiated.  So it's not possible to have a Creator instance which lacks a `factoryMethod`.